# Examples of badly recorded/EQed ADR

Tags: bad, adr

Hi there,

I am looking for some good, contemporary examples of badly recorded/EQed/mixed ADR from either movies or TV shows. The kind of ADR that sounds boxy, poor perspective etc. I know that "Bones" is a good example but does anyone else have any other good examples.

Tha

Comment: I think it's a little harsh to outright call an entire show broadly as having bad ADR.  Sometimes it hit and miss on a episodic basis.  Some episodes of a show, everything gels.  Sometimes, it just won't.  Honestly I'm impressed that all the necessary ADR gets shot for TV episodes considering the post sound turnaround times.  Working against the clock often.

Answer (score 3):

Not to sound like a an old nag, but I'm not really sure its that productive (or perhaps fair) to single out particular instances of 'bad' ADR in film or TV. There are possibly many reasons why something doesn't sound like you expect it should (director/producer making the call, time/budget constraints etc etc) and I expect the person doing the mixing or editing is well aware that it doesn't sound that great and is perhaps reluctant to 'sign it off', but sometimes things don't always end up how you planned! 
I see and hear it quite often when there is mismatched ADR and it does grate on me bit (especially on the bigger budget films where you'd expect it to be better) but then again you don't always know how bad it sounded to start with!

And I guess for just general politeness its not great to start 'slagging off' other peoples work too. You never know when you might end up working with them at some point ;)

Answer (score 1):

WHITE COLLAR is quite bad too

Answer (score 1):

Bad ADR:

- The Constant Gardener - during the 'advice' scene near the end when Ralph has a revealing conversation in the car at night. The driver is ADR'd over an OTS shot.
- Gangs of New York - after Leonardo wakes up in his bed of naked chicks (1/2 way through the film). Our butcher says a line with 'ignominious' during a reaction shot.
- The Bourne Identity - when Matt Damon is outside the embassy (1/3 way into film or so) - he speaks German over a reaction shot.
- The X-Files - Season 1 - "Fire" when Mulder speaks to his british ex-GF in the hospital - it is lip sync'd but obviously ADR - the tone changes completely.
- IT - (1/2 way through) - when the two buddies are walking from the book store talking about the clown in the street - lip-sync'd, but obvious tone change.

B. Moore

Answer (score 0):

Two that really stick in my mind of recent times are the tv series Last Resort and the film The Great Gatsby.

I sat down while my housemate was watching Last Resort last year and caught a scene where they are talking on the beach. Everything about it was bad. Terrible performances, bad perspective, horrible sync. I think the show got cancelled after theforst season.

The Great Gatsby has some of the worst ADR I've heard in a film which was surprising considering the high production values of the visuals and rest of the soundtrack. From memory it's worst in the scene where Gatsby is driving his car really fast over the bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Two examples I can think of:

- Speed. When Hopper’s character says to Keanu ‘I want you back real fast!’ Is completely different to his lips.

Milk. Sean Penn says to Emile Hirsch ‘If you can do it...’ his lips don’t move and the dialogue sounds quite tinny